# Read Only/Write Protected USB pen drive is not write protected on other PCs

Tags: usb, read-only, diskpart

I want to make one of my USB drive write protected. I can make it write protected on my desktop(windows 8.1 pc) by using the command prompt "diskpart" method. Now the usb is write protected on my desktop I cannot delete/move or format the usb drive on the desktop but If I plug the usb to my other 2 laptops then I can easily delete the files contained on the usb drive.

I can even format the drive on other 2 laptops. So What's the point it is write protected?

One of the Laptop is windows 8.1 and other one is windows 7.

I want to make the usb write protected across all the PCs so when I plug it on any pc, my pcs and any other public pc I will not be able to delete/format files from the usb.

Answer (score -2):

hi  try this software (USB Write Protect 2.0)
http://www.softpedia.com/get/Security/Security-Related/USB-Write-Protect.shtml

or this one 
http://usb-writeprotector.en.softonic.com/download

Comment: Would be good if you could explain how to use these programs specifically, and why you recommend them.